# Convert datetime to ISO Format using moment js

Tags: javascript, datetime, typescript, ionic2, momentjs

I want to convert date time to iso to display it to ion-datetime in ionic

Here's my .html code

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label stacked>Date</ion-label>
  <ion-datetime [min]="minFrom" [max]="maxFrom" displayFormat="hh:mm a"></ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
```

Here's my .ts code

```
  var start = moment('08:00 AM', 'hh:mm A');
  var end = moment('04:00 PM', 'hh:mm A').subtract(30, 'm');
  if(end < start) {
    end = end.add(1, 'd');
  }
  var minTime = moment(start, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm');
  var maxTime = moment(end, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm');
  console.log(minTime);
  console.log(maxTime);
  console.log("=====================");
  this.minFrom = moment(minTime, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss').toISOString();
  this.maxFrom = moment(maxTime, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss').toISOString();
  console.log(this.minFrom);
  console.log(this.maxFrom);
```

The output gives me

```
=====================
2017-10-20 08:00
2017-10-21 16:30
=====================
2017-10-20T00:00:00.000Z
2017-10-20T08:30:00.000Z
```

Why is that the ISO Format gives different value

expected output

```
=====================
2017-10-20 08:00
2017-10-21 16:30
=====================
2017-10-20T08:00:00.000Z
2017-10-21T16:30:00.000Z
```

here's a sample fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/zpt30706/1/

Comment: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-iso-string/

Comment: '2017-10-20 08:00' is interpreted as local, 2017-10-20T00:00:00.000Z is UTC. It seems your timezone is GMT-0800 (USA Pacific Standard Time or Alaska Daylight Time?), so they are the same moment in time in different time zones (-0800 and +0000 respectively).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of your existing code is fine.

```
var start = moment('08:00 AM', 'hh:mm A');
var end = moment('04:00 PM', 'hh:mm A').subtract(30, 'm');
if(end < start) {
  end = end.add(1, 'd');
}
```

Since you already have moment objects, you can now just format them as desired.

```
this.minFrom = start.format('YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm');
this.maxFrom = end.format('YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm');
console.log(this.minFrom);
console.log(this.maxFrom);
```

Output:

```
2017-10-20T08:00
2017-10-20T15:30
```

Note that you had *subtracted* 30 minutes from 16:00, so you get 15:30.  If you actually wanted 16:30, then you should *add* 30 minutes instead.